# diskpart on RDM's 

Tags: cluster, vmware-esxi, hard-drive

HI,

We have ESXi cluster which is attached to clariion CX4

We have windows 2008 R2 as the guest OS.

Attahed to this vm is 2 x 1.95T RDM's

I select disk 1 > create partition primary size=1 (1MB) > then list partition
Partition ### Type Size Offset

```
* Partition 1 Primary 1024 KB 1024 KB
```

Then I do the same for the other disk and offset is 1024KB

I need to present 4T disk to this vm so I right click on disk 1 > convert to simple volume > then extend it by adding the second disk

now when I do list partition, I see the off set is set to 31k.

Can anyone please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure windows 2008 manages the offset for you and you don't need to use diskpart to set them check
[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738145%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) [and Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814.aspx)